# unable select combobox value after form is loaded

Tags: c#, winforms

cant select combo item by value after its passed to form. Comb is populated properly i get all the customers displayed by Text.

```
public OrderViewerForm(string orderId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateCustomerCombobox();
        
        PopulateForm(orderId);

        PopulateProductsTable();
    }

private void PopulateForm(string orderId)
    {
        OrderModel order = db.LoadOrder(orderId);

        List<ProductsOrderedModel> productsOrdered = db.ProductsOrdered_Load(orderIdValue.Text);

        orderIdValue.Text = order.Id.ToString();
        customerIdValue.Text = order.CustomerId.ToString();
        

        customerIdCombo.SelectedValue = order.CustomerId;

        
    }

private void PopulateCustomerCombobox()
    {
        customerIdCombo.Items.Clear();
        List<CustomerModel> customer = db.CustomerGet_All();

        foreach (CustomerModel c in customer)
        {
            customerIdCombo.DisplayMember = "Text";
            customerIdCombo.ValueMember = "Value";

            customerIdCombo.Items.Add(new { Text = c.FullInfo, Value = c.Id });
        }
    }
```

At the end `order.CustomerId` is set properly but `customerIdCombo.SelectedValue` stays null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving setting SelectedValue into the Shown Event of the form.

Comment: @Ralf it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest switching to databinding here. Your foreach looks weird by the way.

```
private void PopulateCustomerCombobox()
{
    customerIdCombo.DisplayMember = "Text";
    customerIdCombo.ValueMember = "Value";

    customerIdCombo.DataSource = db.CustomerGet_All().Select(c=> new { Text = c.FullInfo, Value = c.Id});
}
```

Thinking about it you may want to drop the hole anonymous type thing. why not simply bind the list you get from CustomerGet_All?

Comment: binding its value member and display member helped, now selected value works fine thanks.